Extracting CSV like data from a JSON object via API POST call
Unable to dig deeper in the JSON object to extract the CSV like data that is stored in there as the payload of the API call.
When reading the data from the output of the call it shows as;
{
   "error":"None",
   "filterValues":[
      
   ],
   "payload":"Department Tracker,User Department Name,User Name,Time Off Type,Booking Start Date,Booking End Date,Time Off Hrs,Time Off Days,Approval Status,Time Off Comments,Employee ID,User Email,External\r\nxxx.BE.ADMIN,Administration,\"xx, xx\",Vacation previous year,14/02/22,14/02/22,4.00,0.50,Approved,,xx,xx@xx.eu,NO\r\\xxxx.BE.ADMIN,Administration,\"xx, xx\",Vacation previous year,21/02/22,21/02/22,8.00,1.00,Approved,,xxx,xx.xx@xx.eu,NO\r\n....."
}

I need to create a dataframe based on the data after the payload section.
